# Js split function acting strange

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split

my issue

```
challenge1 = () =>  {
var data = fs.readFileSync('santa21.txt', 'utf8');
data = data.toString();
dataSplit = data.split(' ')
console.log(dataSplit);
};
challenge1();
```

The output of dataSplit

```
 [
'1973\r\n' +  
'1755\r\n' +
'1601\r\n' +
'1852\r\n' +
'493\r\n' + 
'1905\r\n' +
'1752\r\n' +
'1946\r\n' +
'1608\r\n' +
'1438\r\n' +
'1383\r\n' +
'1281\r\n' +
'1918\r\n' +
'1125\r\n' +
'1624\r\n' +
'1802\r\n' +
'1513\r\n' +
'1574\r\n' +
'1871\r\n' +
'1831\r\n' +
'1842\r\n' +
'1869\r\n' +
'1982\r\n' +
'1027\r\n' +
    ....]
```

I fixed it by doing:

```
challenge1 = () =>  {
var data = fs.readFileSync('santa21.txt', 'utf8');
data = data.toString();
dataSplit = data.split('\r\n')
console.log(dataSplit);
};
```

This is the "santa21.txt" file: [santa21.txt](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1/input)

> 1973 1755 1601 1852 493 1905 1752 1946 1608 1438 1383 1281 1918
> 1125 1624 1802 1513 1574 1871 1831 1842 1869 1982 1027 1009 1020 1016
> 1336 1519 1721 1960 1889 1299 1355 1622 399 1919 1749 1709 1425 1789
> 1620 1071 1248 1786 1879 1208 1697 1643 1510 1578 1152 1592 1985 1653
> 1112 591 1784 1393 1607 1130 1054 1120 1619 1029 1453 1850 1451 1753
> 1483 1021 1553 1561 1656 1975 1600 1677 1912 1334 1526 1345 1115 2010
> 1758 1664 1102 1588 1339 1745 1605 1638 1599 1741 1147 1837 1142 1774
> 1562 1936 1810 1648 1576 1794 1621 1194 1246 1727 1915 1793 1037 1587
> 1103 1947 1116 1567 1528 1964 1163 1980 1672 1773 1593 1586 169 1613
> 1712 1854 1632 1760 1182 1812 1811 1660 1728 1067 1835 1501 1335 1647
> 1853 543 1108 1024 1559 1717 1826 1544 1585 1655 1386 1331 1485 1537
> 1290 1941 1734 2003 1151 1679 1782 1783 1146 1277 1766 1900 530 1955
> 1268 1968 1432 1170 1867 1005 1202 1564 1096 1707 1309 1094 1295 1974
> 1404 1229 1883 1838 1997 1536 408 1149 1945 1454 1856 1792 1614 1492
> 1823 1803 1533 1726 1364

it's a challenge from the adventofcode, i would know why is it outputting the \r and \n.

Comment: The link doesn't work, it's different for each user and you have to be logged in.

Comment: But it looks like the problem is that the file doesn't have spaces between the numbers, they're on separate lines.

Comment: `\r\n` is carriage return and newline.

Comment: just use `data.split(/\s+/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cause of

```
 [
 '1973\r\n' +  
 '1755\r\n' +
 '1601\r\n' +
 1852\r\n' +
 '493\r\n' + 
 '1905\r\n' +
 '1752\r\n' +
```

are the regualr exrperrions, **"\r\n"** is considered as new line.
More info [here](https://regexr.com/)